# Can Kinect detect if a person is laying down?

Tags: kinect

I would like to use the Kinect to verify if a person fell down. The person will be layng down on the floor, no movement. I can't use skeletonTracking cause there is no movement and I can't track the joints. I was thinking of putting the Kinect on the ceiling, pointing to the floor, but I still don't know how to verify if there is a person lying on the floor. Any ideas? Any good reference?

Comment: The lack of movement does not prevent you from tracking joints.  Will the person enter the scene and then lay on the floor, or could the Kinect be turned on and asked to identify if a person is already laying on the floor?

Comment: The Kinect will turn on when the person is already laying on the floor.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey The Kinect will turn on when the person is already laying on the floor. Any suggestion?

Comment: @nabrugir What Kinect SDK are you using ? (e.g. libfreenect/OpenNI/Microsoft Kinect SDK/etc.) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I use the Microsoft Kinect SDK. Would it be possible with the OpenNI?

Comment: You can try a quick'n'dirty test with OpenNI: use the Scene Image to segment a person from the background. Once you've done that, you can check for two thing: the user's bounding box is less tall than threshold value and the position of the highest point on the bounding box is lower than a threshold then your user might be on the ground. This would detect the position, not the gesture of falling. Another idea is to use the CoM (centre of mass) openni functionality and check if that's lower than a value. Checking for current/previous CoM will give you a velocity vector...

Comment: ...if the velocity on the vertical axis is greater than a threshold, the user might be falling. These are just simple approaches. You can also look into gesture recognition, DTW (dynamic time warping) in particular to define a fall gesture

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks fro the suggestion. Does the Scene Image segment a person even if the person is not moving? The SkeletonTracking from the Microsoft SDK doesn't work if the person is already laying on the floor when the kinect turns on.

Comment: From my experience, if you stand completely still, OpenNI too might not pickup a person, but is pretty good at picking up the person after small movements (head tilts a bit, an arm moves a bit, etc.). I recommend running a test with your setup. You can do so without any coding, simply run one of the samples which use scene segmentation(e.g. Sample-NiUserSelection,Sample-NiUserTracker,Sample-NiSimpleSkeleton - skeleton's not needed, but before it's tracked you can see the scene image too).